# Block writing in sections of registry run, services, drivers

Tags: drivers, boot, windows-registry, services

I'm looking for a program block (ask me for permission) writing in sections of registry Run (RunOnce), Services, Drivers. Before I used Ad-Aware 1.06, but now it's out of date. New versions Ad-Aware came with antivirus and other unnecessary functionality.
Can anybody advise me any program with similar functionality?